# Issue processing data read from serial port, when displaying it in a Tkinter textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

So i am reading (and displaying with a tkinter textbox) data from a serial connection, but i can't process the returning data as i would like to, in order to run my tests. In more simple terms, even though the `machine response = 0x1` is displayed, i can't read it from the global `serBuffer`.

Before displaying it to the `textbox` i would read from inside the  test `function` and then check if the response was in the `string`, but now that i pass the read data(strings) to a global variable and then try to read it, it doesn't seem to work, UNLESS i remove  the `serBuffer = ""` from `readserial`. That results in a new issue though. When i press the button to send the command it sends it, but only receives the response after the second time i press it, and every time after. So as a result i get a `Fail` if i run the test once, but i get a pass everytime after.

Picture with the **desired response** ( that the `test function` doesn't read 0x1 and always returns FAIL)

[image: Image with the correct response that i am unable to read and get a pass or fail]

Picture with the **non-desired** response ( that only receives the response after the second time a press it, and every time after. So as a result i get a Fail if i run the test once, but i get a pass every time after).

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
from serial import *


serialPort = "COM3"
baudRate = 115200
ser = Serial(serialPort, baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0) #ensure non-blocking


#make a TkInter Window
mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.wm_title("Reading Serial")
mainWindow.geometry('1650x1000+500+100')




scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(mainWindow)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

log = tk.Text ( mainWindow, width=60, height=60, takefocus=0)
log.pack()

log.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=log.yview)

#make our own buffer
#useful for parsing commands
#Serial.readline seems unreliable at times too
serBuffer = ""
ser.write(b'\r\n')

def readSerial():
    while True:
        c = (ser.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))  # attempt to read a character from Serial
        # was anything read?
        if len(c) == 0:
            break

        # get the buffer from outside of this function
        global serBuffer

        # check if character is a delimeter
        if c == '\r':
            serBuffer += "\n" # don't want returns. chuck it

        if c == '\n':
            serBuffer += "\n"  # add the newline to the buffer

            # add the line to the TOP of the log
            log.insert('1.1', serBuffer)
            serBuffer = ""  # empty the buffer
        else:
            serBuffer += c  # add to the buffer

    mainWindow.after(100, readSerial)  # check serial again soon

def test():
    command = b" test command \r\n"
    ser.write(command)
    global serBuffer
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if "0x1" in serBuffer:
        print('PASS')
        return 'PASS'
    else:
        print('FAIL')
        return 'FAIL'

button = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Pone Test", font=40, bg='#b1c62d', command=test)
button.place(relx=0.8, rely=0, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.05)


# after initializing serial, an arduino may need a bit of time to reset
mainWindow.after(100, readSerial)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: You do `serBuffer = ""  # empty the buffer` before `if "0x1" in serBuffer:`. Divide into a `local read_buffer` and a `global last_command`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you edit my code to understand what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes, check this one.

```
def readSerial():
    while True:
        c = (ser.read(1).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')) from Serial

        if len(c) == 0:
            break


        global serBuffer
        if c == '\r':
            serBuffer += "" 

        if c == '\n':
            serBuffer += "\n" 



            log.insert(tk.END, serBuffer)
            log.see(tk.END)
            log.update_idletasks()
            serBuffer = ""  
        else:
            serBuffer += c  

    mainWindow.after(500, readSerial)
```

Answer (score 6):

> **Comment**:  but only receives the response after the second time a press it, and every time after. So as a result i get a Fail if i run the test once, but i get a pass everytime after

Raise the first, timeout from `100` to `500` ore more.

```
        # after initializing serial, an arduino may need a bit of time to reset
        mainWindow.after(100, self.readSerial)
```

---

To find out the **delay** for the first response, try the following:

> **Note**: You have to do this without running `def readSerial`, to prevent concurent empty the `in buffer`"

```
    command = b" test command \r\n"
    self.ser.write(command)

    delay = 0.0

    # wait until you get `.in_waiting` data.
    while not self.ser.in_waiting:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        delay += 0.1
        print('.', end='')
        if delay >= 10:
            print('BREAK after {} no in_waiting'.format(int(delay * 10)))
            break

    print('Delay:{}, in_waiting:{}'.format(delay, self.ser.in_waiting))
```

---

The following works for me.

> **Note**: I use `OOP` syntax.

1. `last_command`

   ```
   serBuffer = ""
   last_command = None
   ```
2. Copy the ready `read_buffer` to `last_command`, empty only `read_buffer`

   ```
   def readSerial(self):
       while True:
           c = (self.ser.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))  # attempt to read a character from Serial
           # was anything read?
           if len(c) == 0:
               break

           # get the buffer from outside of this function
           global serBuffer

           # check if character is a delimeter
           if c == '\r':
               serBuffer += "\n"  # don't want returns. chuck it

           if c == '\n':
               serBuffer += "\n"  # add the newline to the buffer

               global last_command
               last_command = serBuffer

               # add the line to the TOP of the log
               # log.insert('1.1', last_command)
               print('readSerial.last_command:"{}"'.format(bytes(last_command, 'utf-8')))

               serBuffer = ""  # empty the buffer

           else:
               serBuffer += c  # add to the buffer
               print('readSerial:"{}"'.format(bytes(serBuffer, 'utf-8')))

       self.after(100, self.readSerial)  # check serial again soon
   ```
3. Do `test()`

   ```
   def test(self, write=True):
       print('test(write={})'.format(write))

       if write:
           command = b" test command \r\n"
           self.ser.write(command)
           self.after(500, self.test, False)

       elif last_command is not None:
           print('last_command:{}'.format(bytes(last_command, 'utf-8')))

           if "0x1" in last_command:
               print('PASS')
           else:
               print('FAIL')
       else:
           # ATTENTION: This could lead to a infinit loop
           # self.after(500, self.test, False)
           pass
   ```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> test(write=True)
> readSerial:"b' '"
> readSerial:"b' t'"
> readSerial:"b' te'"
> readSerial:"b' tes'"
> readSerial:"b' test'"
> readSerial:"b' test '"
> readSerial:"b' test c'"
> readSerial:"b' test co'"
> readSerial:"b' test com'"
> readSerial:"b' test comm'"
> readSerial:"b' test comma'"
> readSerial:"b' test comman'"
> readSerial:"b' test command'"
> readSerial:"b' test command '"
> readSerial:"b' test command \n\r'"
> readSerial.last_command:"b' test command \n\r\n'"
> test(write=False)
> last_command:b' test command \n\r\n'
> FAIL
> ```
>
> **Note**: I get `FAIL`, because there is no `0x1` in `last_command` as i use `PORT = 'loop://'` which echo what is writen!

Comment: i am getting an error : `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Comment: Then your `def readSerial():` does not reach `last_command = serBuffer`. This means you didn't receive anything or you are to early to do `if "0x1" in last_command:`

Comment: i will add some delay to see if it solved the problem, thank you for the help!

Comment: ok apparently bumping up the delay didn't make it work, i also tried the `ser.send_break` and that didn't work either. I am pretty sure i am receiving data though, i have done it when i am not displaying it to the textbox. The only difference is that i am reading from Pycharm

Comment: @Deezer: ***`time.sleep(0.5)`***: Ohhh, this will **block** your `.after(...` which leads to **no** `readSerial()` at all. Replace with `.after(500)`.

Comment: Hm that didn't seem to work either, i removed `time.sleep` and bumped up the after to (500), same thing unfortunately

Comment: Hm ok i made it work by removing the `serBuffer = "` from 'readserial', BUT when i press the button to send the command it sends it but only receives the response after the second time a press it, and every time after. So as a result i get a Fail if i run the test once, but i get a pass everytime after.

Comment: @Deezer: In the meantime i have installed `pyserial` and i found, `def readSerial():` does not run `async`.

Comment: I am not really familiar with async, does it effect us? I searched a bit and found something called `asyncio`. Would that solve the problem?(if there is one)

Comment: @Deezer: Update my answer, with a **TEST** about the first delay.