# trying to get data from serial port to display in Tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port

I am trying to get information from a charger using serial ports, I cant seem how to get the Tkinter message box to show up with the information I'm calling. I believe the information is being received fine because the time and date is still displayed on the Power Shell with every iteration. Can anyone tell me how to get the message box to appear when the button for the port is clicked?

```
# import modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import serial
from numpy import array
import string
import time
import os, sys
import datetime
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

init()
global testflag
global v1, v2, v3, capacity, pass_fail
testflag = 0

#setting up connection with serial port
try:
    ser = serial.Serial('COM9')
    ser.baudrate = 4800
    ser.bytesize = 8
    ser.parity = 'N'
    ser.stopbites = 1
    ser.timeout = 40
except:
    print("#################################################")
    print("# Serial Port could not be found. Exiting ..... #")
    print("#################################################")
    sys.exit()


# configure workspace
ws = Tk()
ws.title("COM Ports")
ws.geometry('500x150')

#defining functions for commands
def get_com():
    #initialize dictionary
    testvars = {}

    def init_testvars():
        testvars['Capacity'] = 0
        testvars['Vpack'] = 0
        testvars['V1'] = 0
        testvars['V2'] = 0
        testvars['V3'] = 0
        testvars['Current'] = 0
        testvars['Vpack'] = 0
        testvars['Temp'] = 0
        testvars['Version'] = 0
        testvars['Cycles'] = 0

    init_testvars()
    os.system('cls')


    #creating continuous loop so the program displays information as it is sent
    while True:
        lenread = 0
        while lenread < 1:
            outBytes = ser.read()           #wait for anything
            lenread = len(outBytes)
        time.sleep(4)
        data_left = ser.inWaiting()
        outBytes += ser.read(data_left)
        outStr = outBytes.decode()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        info = array(outStr)
        os.system('cls')

        findsum = outStr.find('V1') + outStr.find('V2')+outStr.find('V3')
        findsum += outStr.find('VPACK') + outStr.find('CAPACITY')
        if findsum != -5:
            print ("> " + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " <")
            nindex = outStr.find('V1')
            if nindex != -1:
                testvars['V1'] = float(outStr[nindex+23:nindex+28])
                v1 = "Voltage 1 = {:.3f} V".format(testvars['V1'])
            else:
                v1 = "v1 Not Found!"

            nindex = outStr.find('V2')
            if nindex != -1:
                testvars['V2'] = float(outStr[nindex+23:nindex+28])
                v2 = "Voltage 2 = {:.3f} V".format(testvars['V2'])
            else:
               v2 = "v2 Not Found!"

            nindex = outStr.find('V3')
            if nindex != -1:
                testvars['V3'] = float(outStr[nindex+23:nindex+28])
                v3 = "Voltage 3 = {:.3f} V".format(testvars['V3'])
            else:
                v3 = "v3 Not Found!"
            
            nindex = outStr.find('VPACK')
            if nindex != -1:
                testvars['Vpack'] = float(outStr[nindex+23:nindex+29])
                vpack = "VPack     = {:.3f} V".format(testvars['Vpack'])
            else:
                vpack = "vpack Not Found!"

            nindex = outStr.find('CAPACITY')
            if nindex != -1:
                testvars['Capacity']  = float(outStr[nindex+11:nindex+13])
                capacity = "Capacity  = {:.1f} %".format(testvars['Capacity'])
            else:
                capacity = "Capacity Not Found!"
        
        #creating pass/fail contraints
        v1_3 = abs(testvars['V1'] - testvars['V3'])
        v1_2 = abs(testvars['V1'] - testvars['V2'])
        v2_3 = abs(testvars['V2'] - testvars['V3'])

        #only pass when voltages are within 50V of eachother
        if ((v1_3 < 50) and (v1_2 < 50) and (v2_3 < 50)):
            pass_fail = colored("#######PASS########", "green")
        else:
            pass_fail = colored("#######FAIL#######", "red")
                            
        init_testvars()
    
        outStr = ' '

def show_com11():
    get_com()
    v1 = "V1 = " + testvars['V1']
    v2 = "/nV2 = " + testvars['V2']
    v3 = "/nV3 = " + testvars['V3']
    total = v1 + v2 + v3 + pass_fail
    ser.close()
    return messagebox.showinfo("COM11", str(total))


#creating buttons for each COM port
com11 = Button(ws, text="COM11", command = show_com11)

ws.mainloop()
```

Please note that I am only working on the COM11 port for now but  i have included all code

UPDATE: condensed code to only what was asked about

Comment: Please don't include code that isn't directly relevant to the question. Distill it down into a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley Understood, that doesnt fix my problem though

Comment: If your goal is to solve your problem, it is in your best interest to give the smallest example possible that illustrates your problem. People don't like to wade through 150 lines of code to try to understand the problem. For example, is it really necessary to search through the data for various strings? How does that affect the problem? If the question is about reading and displaying data, can't you just display exactly what was read?

Comment: `testvars` and `pass_fail` are local variables inside `get_com()`, so they cannot be accessed inside `show_com11()`.

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [Issue processing data read from serial port, when displaying it in a Tkinter textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691056/9014308), [Reading serial input and printing to Tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52010473/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

The example code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from tkinter import messagebox

import time

#luodaan kuva...
ikkuna=tkinter.Tk()
ikkuna.title("Serial data read & show values & message box -example")
ikkuna.geometry("800x400")


kanvaasi=Canvas(ikkuna,width=800,height=400)
kanvaasi.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

kanvaasi.create_text(370,80,text="V1")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,130,text="V2")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,180,text="V3")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,220,text="VPack")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,270,text="Capacity")

def read():
    global v1,v2,v3,vpack,capacity
    global kv1,kv2,kv3,kv4,kv5

    #this is only simulation, in real case replace the simulation code with the real one...
    v1=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    v2=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    v3=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    vpack=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    capacity=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    #...end of simulation

    try:
        kanvaasi.delete(kv1)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv2)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv3)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv4)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv5)
    except:
        pass

    #let's update the tkinter accordingly...
    kv1=kanvaasi.create_text(430,80,text=v1)
    kv2=kanvaasi.create_text(430,130,text=v2)
    kv3=kanvaasi.create_text(430,180,text=v3)
    kv4=kanvaasi.create_text(430,220,text=vpack)
    kv5=kanvaasi.create_text(430,270,text=capacity)

    #if some rules are true, let's also show a message box...
    if v1>0.5:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Serial',message=''.join(['V1 = ',np.str(v1)]))
    if v2>0.5:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Serial',message=''.join(['V2 = ',np.str(v2)]))
    if v3>0.5:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Serial',message=''.join(['V3 = ',np.str(v3)]))
    if vpack>0.5:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Serial',message=''.join(['Vpack = ',np.str(vpack)]))
    if capacity>0.5:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Serial',message=''.join(['Capacity = ',np.str(capacity)]))


painike1=Button(ikkuna,text="Read",command=read,height=14,width=20)
painike1_ikkuna=kanvaasi.create_window(120,70,anchor="nw",window=painike1)


ikkuna.mainloop()
```

...advices you how to implement the tkinter-part about how to show the values from the serial data, and how to show the message box. Please copy and paste your essential code parts from your original code and - touche - that's it!

[image]